# How can I make not select text for "Copy/Paste" UITextView

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

I want to have a UITextView in my code that you can scroll up and down, but I DO NOT want to be able to:

1) Edit it.

2) Select any of the text for "Copy/Paste".

I'm able to solve 1). I just uncheck "Editable" in the Interface Builder.

But I can't for the life of me work out how to stop the user from being able to highlight and select text.

I would imagine the solution could be along the lines of inheriting a class from UITextView and overriding one of the functions.  But I'm not sure which one and how.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,
- Rich

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, just subclass it and rewrite:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without subclassing

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```